# Quickblox API Connectivity

Tags: ios, objective-c, quickblox

I want to connect quickblox api in my Xcode 6 project. But importing drag and drop quickblox.framework to project, after adding header `#import <quickblox/quickblox.h>` it shows error their no build module quickblox. Also I have do same like written in quickblox docs linker flags and header search path. But no connectivity.

[image: error shown]

[image: linker flags]

Answer (score 0):

Open your Podfile and add following line:

```
pod 'QuickBlox
```

Than open Terminal go to your project folder with Podfile and run:

```
pod install
```

get more details from here 
http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS-how-to-connect-Quickblox-framework

Answer (score 0):

It's better for you to build your app from the sample of Quickblox. I think Quickblox SDK for iOS has bug.

An other way, you can disable bit-code for your project, I tried success